# jQuery On Change Method Does Not Work Out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and have added this code for changing html output based on select option like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('body').on('change','#theSelect', function() {
         var value = $("#theSelect option:selected").val();
         if(value === "98"){
            $('.free').show();
            $('.price-show').hide();
         }else {
            $('.free').hide();
            $('.price-show').show();
         }
    });
});
```

And this is the html:

```
<select id="theSelect">
      <option value="98">New York</option>
      <option value="108">Los Angeles</option>
      <option value="118">San Fransisco</option>
</select>
        
<small class="price-show">
   800 $
</small>
<small class="free">
   Free
</small>
```

But now the problem, it does not even workout.

Live Example: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pouyavey/58pf2szg/11/)

So would you mind please tell me how to solve this and change html output when user selects different value from select option correctly?

I would really appreciate that

Comment: Your jsfiddle-example is missing jQuery-reference are you by any chance missing it in your project too?

Comment: add jQuery CDN in fiddle, you can see error in log there.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that you have not included the jQuery library in your code. So `$` is undefined.

You will also need to trigger an initial change on the `#theSelect` element so that it adjusts itself according to the initial value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('change', '#theSelect', function() {
    var value = $("#theSelect option:selected").val();
    if (value === "98") {
      $('.free').show();
      $('.price-show').hide();
    } else {
      $('.free').hide();
      $('.price-show').show();
    }
  });
  $('#theSelect').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="theSelect">
  <option value="98">New York</option>
  <option value="108">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="118">San Fransisco</option>
</select>

<small class="price-show">
   800 $
</small>
<small class="free">
   Free
</small>
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like you're not adding jquery cdn

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('body').on('change','#theSelect', function() {
         var value = $("#theSelect option:selected").val();
         if(value === "98"){
           $('.free').show();
           $('.price-show').hide();
        }else {
           $('.free').hide();
           $('.price-show').show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="theSelect">
      <option value="98">New York</option>
      <option value="108">Los Angeles</option>
      <option value="118">San Fransisco</option>
</select>
        
<small class="price-show">
   800 $
</small>
<small class="free">
   Free
</small>
```

you are not using jquery cdn, it must be there to make your code work